Is there something I can do to encourage MicroSoft Defender to get additional intelligence when scanning? ie Defender Event ID 2010
Is it possible to safely make Defender want to download extra definitions during a scan?
Reason for asking:-
I am looking for a pattern or possible cause of strange behaviour.
A Windows 10 PC no longer gets any additional intelligence updates when running Microsoft Defender Anti-virus (Shows as Defender event ID 2010).
During a full scan, it sometimes get events 7000 & 7009 about services timing out. And Diagnosis-DPS error 135 about radardt.dll.
I'm wondering if it could be a resources issue, and if these things are happening when it tries to get the definitions. It does not get these errors at other times.
The usual Defender antivirus protection updates work fine.
Background:-
I have two PCs running Windows 10 Home. They both have the same settings in Defender. One often gets additional intelligence updates while scanning. The other used to get these updates, but has had none since the end of January.
I always check for definitions before a scan. The missing updates are the extras that I believe are part of Defender's cloud-protection.
MalwareBytes full scan has been run regularly and has found nothing.
Edit - Update:-
I ran this... MpCmdRun.exe" -ValidateMapsConnection on both PCs.
Both said: ValidateMapsConnection successfully established a connection to MAPS
(As I understand that Defender cloud protection is a part of MAPS that you get access to with Windows 10 home)
To clarify the question, is there a safe action that often results in the next Defender scan wanting these additional intelligence files (as seen in Defender Event 2010 "Microsoft Defender Antivirus used cloud protection to get additional security intelligence")? For example, running or updating a particular program, or saving a particular type of file?

What error code is being shown in Windows Update for the fail definition updates failing to install? How exactly did you determine one machine definitions are updating and the other is not updating?

@Ramhound Not an error. A desired event. One PC, gets Microsoft-Windows-Windows Defender/Operational, Event 2010 "Microsoft Defender Antivirus used cloud protection to get additional security intelligence" The other used to, but not since January. The mentioned service timeout errors etc, only happen during a scan, and only on the PC that does not get the additional updates.

@John WD gets the regular protection updates as usual, and when I check for them, just not the additional ones from Microsofts cloud protection during a scan.

@John When I said "One often gets additional intelligence updates while scanning. The other used to get these updates, but has had none since the end of January." I meant "additional intelligence" as in Event 2010 "... Antivirus used cloud protection to get additional security intelligence". The usual Defender antivirus protection updates work fine.
